# Good house rules for 1-on-1 game

Tags: dnd-5e, house-rules, one-on-one

I'm DMing a game for my son so this is his solo game, and first D&D game.  For any dads or anyone else with 1 on 1 gaming experience, what are some good house rules to add?  I was thinking of bonuses like doubling his proficiency, giving him an extra HD per level, extra actions, etc to make his character more survivable.  Especially at low levels, as a single unlucky critical hit can end his game.  But I don't want to break the game.

Something I'd rather not do is just throw 1 enemy at him at a time.  We had 2 encounters so far.  The 1st encounter with 2 goblins was successful but he almost died.  The 2nd encounter with 3 goblins had him drop to 0 HP, but I wrote it off by saying they captured him instead of killing him outright.  For his next session he'll have to find a way to escape.

So rather than just giving him 1 thing to fight every time, what are some other ways I can make his character more survivable while giving him exciting fights?

If it matters, he's a 1st level fighter.

Comment: This seems to be a bit of an XY Problem. You are asking about house rules because you think they are the solution to your problem. I think the question would be better posed by explaining in detail the problem at hand (something about survivability in a single player adventure), and ask for guidance from those with experience running adventures that way.

Comment: Have you considered giving him another character or an NPC to control in combat? I'm not sure of his age, so I don't know if that would be too complex for them, but that would be a way to fix the action economy problem without a bunch of house rules

Comment: Al least related (dupe?): [How to balance combat for a duet campaign with non-frontliner classes?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/157553/52137) (see also the rest of [One on one questions for D&D 5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/one-on-one+dnd-5e))

Comment: I didn't realize opinion-based questions were not allowed here, which is understandable.  However I figured out my problem.  I forgot that encounter challenge ratings was assuming a party of 4 PCs.  So pitting a single 1st level fighter against 2-3 goblins (CR 1/4) was obviously a big challenge.  I will tailor my encounters better for future sessions with him.  Thanks for all your input though.

Answer (score 3):

### I recommend not using house rules.

This is a bit of frame challenge, but I do one on one games from time to time. While I do homebrew a lot of items and equipment, I do not use any overarching house rules and I don't think you need to either. The rules work perfectly fine with one player as long as the game is somewhat tailored to the particular character.

### Tailor the game to him

I think it is always important to tailor your game to the players at the table. This is even more significant with one character since when there is only one character that character cannot expect other characters to fill in the gap in their skillset.

You generally don't want to give a barbarian a quest to sneak through a trap-filled mansion, steal something from a locked chest, and escape without being detected. Similarly, while a rogue probably could handle a mission to eliminate some orcs, it isn't really playing to the rogue's strengths.

Also, tailor the combat to the character. This may mean toning down the challenges, including giving the character fewer and easier enemies.

### Consider increasing the character's power.

You seem to be concerned about your character's survivability. That can be addressed by using milestone leveling and leveling up the character or giving them magical items to make them stronger.

You suggest ways of increasing the power level of the character through house rules. That could work if you really want, but I advise against it. Using house rules to make the character more powerful may make it harder for your player to adjust when he goes to a different table without those house rules. On the other hand, levelling up can be fun. And giving him a quest he can solve without combat that ends in him gaining a significant magical item that then lets him handle the next combat successfully....that if done right can create a sense of accomplishment while he still learns the traditional rules.